# How to add type safety when passing functions as arguments?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm curious as to how to correctly type function parameters, regarding generics.

Looking at the following basic example, I have 2 functions:
- `sayHello` & `runAnyFunction`

Now, the first call to `sayHello` is clearly an error, the data passed to the function doesn't have a `name` parameter. Perfect and expected.

The issue is with the next part, where we have a function `runAnyFunction` that takes a function as its first parameter, `obj` as its second parameter, and simply runs the function passing `obj` as the argument.

The following 2 functions in the sample below will pass typescript checks no problem, and that is my issue.

```
runAnyFunction<Person>(sayHello, {
  name: "Bob"
});

runAnyFunction<Monster>(sayHello, {
  size: "HUGE"
});
```

I know that the second call will give me a `Hello undefined`, which is undesired.  Ideally I'd like this call to fail type checking as this shouldn't be allowed.

My thinking is that the culprit here is the `fn` function parameter, as its own `obj` parameter will be inferred as `any`, but I'm having difficulty writing the correct typing for this.

I understand that in this demo, my `runAnyFunction` is a function that really just runs any function, but if there's a preferred way to type a function of this nature, I would love to know.

How can I correctly type this?

---

Code Sample

```
// demo.ts

type Fn = (obj) => string;

interface Person {
  name: string;
}

interface Monster {
  size: string;
}

const somePerson: Person = {
  name: "Bob"
};

const someMonster: Monster = {
  size: "HUGE"
};


sayHello(someMonster); // ERROR, 'name' is missing in type. Sure, expected.


// sayHello requires an obj of type Person
export function sayHello(obj: Person): string {
  return `Hello ${obj.name}`;
}

// Simple function that runs any function, passing obj to it
export function runAnyFunction<T>(fn: Fn, obj: T): void {
  const res = fn(obj);
  console.log(res);
}

// Person has name, this works
runAnyFunction<Person>(sayHello, {
  name: "Bob"
});

// I'm passing sayHello, which should require an object with a `name`
// but it does not error
runAnyFunction<Monster>(sayHello, {
  size: "HUGE"
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your `Fn` type generic too:

```
type Fn<T> = (obj: T) => string;
export function runAnyFunction<T>(fn: Fn<T>, obj: T): void {
    const res = fn(obj);
    console.log(res);
}
```

The reason that you didn't receive an error before is that your `Fn` type implicity had the `any` type for its first parameter:

```
type Fn = (obj) => string; // obj is implicitly of type any
```

Comment: perfect, makes total sense.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad that you were able to understand such a short explanation.